# Getting an initial error after maas setup

Tags: maas

Getting error: ubuntu xenial is configured as the commissioning release but it is unavailable in the configured streams  This is a brand new one to me as I have set up maas many times, so it must be the new way that images are installed but not sure how to configure this.  Can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

MAAS requires an Ubuntu 16.04+ LTS release to be downloaded. If you are seeing this message MAAS was unable to download Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic on first run.

To correct this:

Click on the “Images” tab and make sure 18.04 LTS is selected and synced.
Click on the “Settings” tab. Then click on the “General” tab in the secondary navigation. Make sure 18.04 is selected and click save.

I realized you have to exit out of the message as it doesn’t clear after it is fixed.

source: https://discourse.maas.io/t/fix-configured-streams/964